# Convert a list of timestamps separate by | (pipe) into a date-selection drop down menu in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

My Sencha Touch 2 web/mobile app is reading in JSON where one of the elements is a list of millisecond timestamps separated by a vertical bar. I would like to convert those timestamps into a human readable form (day-Month, hours) and display them in a selection menu within my form.

Currently, I have a form displaying the data as it is. I know how to implement a dropdown with items, but I'm having trouble doing the date-time conversion and populating the dropdown with the newly converted items.

My JSON looks like this: `"visit-time":"1394416800|1394445600|1394460000|"`

My Sencha Touch form looks like this:

```
{
xtype: 'fieldset',
readOnly: true,
title: 'Visit Information:',
items: [
    {
        name: 'from',
        id: 'from',
        xtype: 'textareafield',
        label: 'From',
        readOnly: true
    },
    {
        name: 'to',
        id: 'to',
        xtype: 'textareafield',
        label: 'To',
        readOnly: true
    },
    {
        name: 'visit-time',
        id: 'visit-time',
        xtype: 'textareafield',
        label: 'Visit Time',
        readOnly: true
    }
]
},
```

Comment: Out of curiousity, why does the backend send the data back like that?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Good question, and unfortunately I do not control that (although I do have some communication with the guy doing the full-scale website). This is more for the mobile side of things, but on the main website users can select a date/time, and confirm multiple dates and times. I'm guessing he did it this way to display local time to each user?

Comment: Are you loading the data via ajax? Model load?

Comment: jsonp proxy, into the model.

Comment: @AmruE. could you please give some feedback on my answer? Has it been helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you have to populate the options of an http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.field.Select with your dates.

You will have to:

- Get `visit-time` and convert it to an array of timestamps using [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- Drop the last element of the array that will be empty using [pop()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)
- Create for each timestamp a Date object with: `new Date(parseInt(timestamp)*1000)`;
- Format your dates with `Ext.Date.format(date, formatString);` check [Ext.Date](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.Date) docs for the formatString.

When you will have your formatted dates into an array, you could just populate the field's store using [Ext.data.Store.setData()](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-setData)